# Change information of music files

Tags: itunes, finder, music

I tried to change the information (cover, album, artist, etc.) of some songs, just double clicking on "information" of any file. I can't change any of them in this way, even if I enter like admin; the only way to change the information is with iTunes, but the information changed is not changed in the user directory.

When I try to play a song with iTunes, automatically any songs are copied in Music → iTunes → iTunes Media → Music. Even if I delete the music files in my user folder, they remain inside the iTunes directory.

Why does this happen? Doesn't make more sense that iTunes copy the link instead than all the file? In this way 2 copies of each files remain on the machine and the memory will be full before for no reason.

How can I change the information on each song in my user folder if double clicking on "information" of any file doesn't change anything?

Answer (score 1):

When you import a file into iTunes and have the option "Copy files to iTunes Media folder when adding to library" it will create a copy and place it into iTunes media folder. You can then delete the original if desired because a copy was made. If you do not have that option checked it will not copy the file.

The reason editing the song info does not affect the file in your user folder is you are actually editing the one that was copied/imported into the iTunes Media folder.